# Откуда здесь берется Key?

Tags: c++, winapi, xor

Нашел вот такую функцию XOR-шифрования, но не понимаю, откуда здесь берется `Key`. У себя попробовал запустить, студия ругается на то, что `Key` не объявлен

```
    LPVOID Crypt(HANDLE hFile, DWORD dwFileSize) {
    LPVOID lpFileBytes = malloc(dwFileSize);
    ReadFile(hFile, lpFileBytes, dwFileSize, NULL, NULL);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < dwFileSize; i++) {
        *((LPBYTE)lpFileBytes + i) ^= Key[i % sizeof(Key)];
    }

    return lpFileBytes;
}
```

Comment: Нужно смотреть там, откуда вы этот код выдернули.

Comment: В том то и дело, там нигде Key не объявлен. Может это какая-то глобальная переменная?
А вообще взял отсюда https://olegon.ru/showthread.php?t=30656
Там Key только 4 раза используется

Comment: Это похоже просто байтовый массив, используемый как ключ. В целом почитайте про xor шифрование.

Comment: А откуда он там взялся, не подскажите? Где его объявили?

Comment: Ну так определите свой `KEY` - какие проблемы? Обязательно использовать их ключ чтоли?

Comment: @qwaaaaz где-то глобально объявили.